# How to make Django-Oscar appear as a separate app in Django admin panel?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-oscar

Good day y'all!

Here comes a basic Django question:

I was running a Django project with one app in it and installed Django-Oscar to cover my ecommerce needs. So, I pip installed it in my main project and set everything up the way they explain it on readthedocs. Now, the structure of my admin panel looks like this:

- Main project

  - My app
  - Oscar Address
  - Oscar Analytics
  - Oscar ...

And I'd like it to be:

- Main project

  - My app
  - Shop

    - Oscar Address
    - Oscar Analytics
    - Oscar ...

I already did django-admin startapp shop for that matter.
Apparently the question is so obvious that I can't find any tutorials for dummies to do this.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Maybe a generic tutorial about including apps in apps the right way is laying around somewhere?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: OK, so kind people from Django's IRC channel (thx knbk) suggested it was not such a good idea to do it this way. They suggested I start writing my own views and forget about the admin pannel. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your question what you're actually trying to achieve, but Oscar does not really 'play nice' with the Django admin, from [the docs](http://docs.oscarcommerce.com/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html#urls):

> But please note that Oscar makes no attempts at having [admin] be a workable interface; admin integration exists to ease the life of developers.

However, if you're just looking to configure the basic oscar functionality there is the Oscar dashboard (at `/dashboard`) which is where the ecommerce functionality is configurable. That can also be [customised with additional views](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/how_to_configure_the_dashboard_navigation.html).